# replace each occurrence of "[i]" with some random number in text file using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I want to replace substring "[i]" with some random number using bash.
e.g.

```
abc.[i].xyz[i].lmn[i]
```

The output should be

```
abc.3.xyz.5.lmn.32
```

here 3, 5, 32 are randomly generated numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

# $result replace_random($search, $replace)
#
# replace all occurrences of $replace in $search with a random number
# in the range 0-32767 using bash's built-in PRNG and return the result
replace_random()
{
    local s=$1
    local replace=$2

    # while $s ($search) contains $replace replace the first occurrence
    # of $replace with a random number.
    # quoting "$replace" forces it to be treated as a simple string
    # and not a pattern to avoid e.g. '[i]' being interpreted as a
    # character class (same holds true for '?' and '*')
    while [[ ${s} == *"${replace}"* ]]; do
        s=${s/"${replace}"/$RANDOM}
    done
    echo "${s}"
}

foo='abc.[i].xyz[i].lmn[i].aab'
bar=$(replace_random "${foo}" "[i]")

echo "foo = [$foo]"
echo "bar = [$bar]"
```

.

```
$ ./t.sh
foo = [abc.[i].xyz[i].lmn[i].aab]
bar = [abc.10103.xyz4641.lmn21264.aab]
```

To force the random numbers into a smaller range you can use e.g.

```
s=${s/"${replace}"/$((RANDOM%64))}
```

which will result in numbers in the range 0 - 63.

Comment: Great answer, I would be happy if you comment your script a little bit, so I (and others) can understand it more easily!

Comment: @Oz123 There you go! :-)

Comment: @Adrian I've not tried the script, so could be talking nonsense, but should there be a `/` after `$RANDOM` or does the closing brace effectively insert one?

Comment: @TripeHound No, this is not `perl` :-) See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). A trailing `/` would be treated as part of the replacement string inserting a literal `/`.

Comment: @Oz123 Heh, not sure what's so special about this simple loop but gerne, jederzeit!

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth - It was actually `vi`/`vim`'s `:s` command I was coming from (where it's not always necessary), but thanks for explaining.

Comment: @TripeHound Ah, well it's not the familiar (regular expression) substitution operator `s///` that one is familiar with from `perl`, `sed`, `vim` et cetera. The `s` here is an arbitrary variable name which is why it looks similar (`result=${string/from/to}`). Since the `}` already denotes the closing of the expansion the parser doesn't need a "closing" slash there.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Makes perfect sense now. While I've done lots of shell-scripting over the years, I've either missed or forgotten that construct. Similar (though probably more powerful) to the DOS   `%VAR:search=replace%`.